# audio.js: is it possible to load an audio at a specific time?

Tags: javascript

i'm using this JS code

```
https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/
```

and I was wondering if i can load and skipt to a specific point of the audio track.

of if there is any other way to do it using an html5 player

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing so would be adding the audio tag programatically using jQuery at a particular point in time like this:

```
jQuery('#audio_wrapper').append(
  jQuery('<audio/>')
  .attr('src','url_of_your_audio_file')
  .attr('id','audio')
);
```

And just after that, make your init code as described by the docs of the library:

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
  var as = audiojs.createAll();
});
```

To skip to a particular time, you can just use jQuery or javascript as if you were manipulating a typical html5 audio:

```
$('#audio').bind('canplay', function() {
  this.currentTime = 29; // jumps to 29th secs
});
```

or javascript:

```
document.getElementById('audio').currentTime=(226);
```